# Is there any limits on CPU, NET?

Tags: staking, resources

I have some questions about CPU, NET resource model.

I know RAM is up to 64GB, and more and more people buy RAM, price will be go high, and vice versa.

But I don't know about CPU and NET. In my think, because cpu and net are temporary, there's no limit so I can stake what I want. (not for ram, because RAM has limit on 64GB which is prepared by BPs..)

Is it right?

And my second question is, how CPU and NET staking price is determined? Unlike RAM, there's no algorithm like Banquor. Is it just Hard-coded in eosio sources?

Comment: This site has a good explanation: https://www.eosrp.io/

Comment: @Nat I know this site and I read what they said. But their explanation didn't answer my question exactly. 


Is the price of CPU/NET determined by the ratio of my staking to the whole user? Or Is the price of CPU/NET hard-coded in source?

Comment: The amount of CPU / NET that you can consume per EOS token is determined by how much CPU / NET is currently being consumed.  The EOSIO protocol will gift additional CPU / NET in times of low overall network use and will take that excess away during times of network saturation.  The price is "hard coded" but I haven't seen someone give an exact explanation as to where the code is or how it works.

Answer (score 1):

RAM is not a constant at 64GB, it is being expanded at a rate of 1KB per block so in a year we will have about double the amount or 128GB.

This rate of change could change in the future, it depends on the system contract and to change it there should be a majority of BP voting to change it.

Regarding CPU and NET, these are temporal, if they are not utilized efficiently at a certain point in time, they are lost forever. Block producers will improve their infrastructure and block.one is working on optimizing the code so more transactions can be processed using a set amount of CPU.

You can stake EOS that you control for CPU or NET and you are limited to the maximum amount of EOS you have. So the cost of CPU and NET is related to the price of EOS at the time you purchased it.

In the future there will be a renting market where you will be able to pay for other peeple's EOS to be staked for your dApp and you won't need to own the EOS out right. This will be cheaper and more flexible.